# Resources for self-dual solutions to Maxwell's equation on Euclidean or pseudo-Euclidean space

Tags: resource-recommendations, maxwell-equations, instantons

I am attempting to understand a question posed to me by an acquaintance, who asked me if I could refer him to literature on "self-dual solutions to Maxwell's equations on Euclidean space, or pseudo-Euclidean space, not Minkowski space (where there are none)" and he labeled them "instantons". I'm lost, so my questions:

1. aren't instantons solutions to equations of motion? Can you consider Maxwell's equations as equations of motion?
2. In what sense are solutions to such equations self-dual, or more simply, what concept of duality is meant here?
3. does anyone have any appropriate literature  to recommend to answer my acquaintance's question?

Any indications on any or all of these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of this: $F+ \sigma\star F$ immediately springs to mind here - with sigma defined by $\star\star F = \pm1=\sigma^2$. You would get truly self Hodge-dual solutions in the case where $\sigma^2=1$, so this would explain why there are no solutions in $3+1$ Minkowski space. It's not as simple as this, is it?

Comment: Rod Vance's answer solved (2) in the question, and explains the parenthetical remark.  (3) was too vague , so clarification: a resource is needed to fit the following: "We need to find in the Euclidean space a self-dual 2-form F = * F that satisfies Maxwell's equations dF = 0. Another group of Maxwell equations is automatically satisfied because the 2-form F is self-dual. Maxwell equations in this case are reduced to 4 first-order partial differential equations with 3 unknown functions. We have found some solutions, and we would like to know what solutions had already been found before us."

Comment: It does seem to fit, but it still may not be the meaning. "Dual" can take on all kinds of meanings, and word meanings get a life of their own when a small group of specialists get hold of them. I've designed optics as a day job for twenty years, and yet I still find the usages of certain words in the radiometry community pretty alien (I don't meet radiometry guys and gals much)- they use certain words in ways that are very different from the way other physicists use them. I made the comment really because I was interested myself in what the meaning of the word is: it'll probably take ...

Comment: .... someone who actually studies these particular solutions to answer definitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On flat $R^4$ the only bounded solutions to $dF=0$, $F=*F$ are linear combinations of the three usual Kahler forms; this is going to be due to $\triangle F = 0$ and so $\triangle |F| \ge 0$ (by the Kato inequality), and the fact that a subharmonic function with 2-sided bounds is constant (a version of Liouville's theorem); then one finds out which solutions F have constant norm, and learns they are just the Kahler forms on $R^4$ (eg. using the identity $\frac12\triangle|F|^2=|\nabla F|^2+\left<\triangle{}F,F\right>$).

On a compact Riemannian 4-manifold, the solutions to $dF=0$, $F=*F$ are precisely given by a cohomology space, the self-dual de Rham space $H^+ \subseteq H^2$. On a non-compact Riemannian 4-manifold the question is harder, and I'm not sure if all bounded solutions to your friend's equations are known in general. Of course there are the $L^2$ de Rham spaces, but computing these is tough, and might or might not provide a satisfactory answer even still.

Needless to say, in 4-dimensional Riemannian geometry, solutions to $dF=0$ where $F$ is a 2-form always split into non-interacting self-dual and anti-self-dual parts, quite in contrast to the Lorentzian case.